# Find the shortest path to the end for multiple starting locations

Tags: algorithm, graph

There is a maze with size N by M, which has walls and corridors. There is gold somewhere in the maze and there are some people in the maze as well. The task is to find what the shortest path from some person to the prize is, as well as which person is going to get the prize.

I know how to solve it if there was only one person, but not if there are more than one.

The input is as follows. On the first line N, M and Q (the number of people are inputted). The on N lines M characters are inputted (. for corridor and # for wall). And then on Q lines the coordinates of each person are inputted.

If some person can get to the gold, the program should output the length of the shortest path and which person gets to it (if more than one get to it at the same time any single one of them is a correct output). And if there is no path the program should output -1.

Comment: Will it be too slow if you just use Dijkstra or w/e for all persons?

Comment: @shole Yes, there can be many people.

Comment: I agree with @indjev99's answer, for a grid, just a simple BFS from the gold is enough, and it should be the best solution you can get in terms of complexity

Comment: Use Djikstra's algorithm but start from the gold, the first person you find has the shortest path to the gold.

Comment: @Fibbles correct but as grid is a special case of graph which each edge is of cost = 1, simple BFS with queue is enough (easier to code for me)

Comment: No diagonal movement then?

Comment: @Fibbles No, no diagonal movement. But I think your answer will be correct if there was diagonal movement with a different cost (for example sqrt(2)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this is to start from the gold and find the shortest path to any person, using BFS (Breadth First Search). Here is my implementation:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<queue>
using namespace std;
const int MAX_N=100; //you didn't say the restrictions so I am going to leave it as a 100
int n,m,q;
char maze[MAX_N][MAX_N];
vector<pair<int,int> > p;
int len[MAX_N][MAX_N]; //stores if we have visited the node and the length to there
int main()
{
    cin>>n>>m>>q;
    for (int i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<m;++j)
        {
            cin>>maze[i][j];
            len[i][j]=-1;
        }
    }
    int x,y;
    for (int i=0;i<q;++i)
    {
        cin>>x>>y;
        --y;
        --x;
        p.push_back(make_pair(y,x));
        maze[y][x]='p';
    }
    /*
    You didn't say when we input the gold's coordinates, so I'm going to assume it is in the end.
    */
    cin>>x>>y;
    --y;
    --x;
    len[y][x]=0;
    queue<pair<int,int> > qu;
    qu.push(make_pair(y,x));
    while (!qu.empty())
    {
        y=qu.front().first;
        x=qu.front().second;
        qu.pop();
        if (maze[y][x]=='p')
        {
            //we have reached a person and just need to find which it is
            for (int i=0;i<q;++i)
            {
                if (p[i].first==y && p[i].second==x)
                {
                    cout<<len[y][x]<<" "<<i+1<<endl;
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
        if (y>0 && maze[y-1][x]!='#' && len[y-1][x]==-1)
        {
            len[y-1][x]=len[y][x]+1;
            qu.push(make_pair(y-1,x));
        }
        if (y<n-1 && maze[y+1][x]!='#' && len[y+1][x]==-1)
        {
            len[y+1][x]=len[y][x]+1;
            qu.push(make_pair(y+1,x));
        }
        if (x>0 && maze[y][x-1]!='#' && len[y][x-1]==-1)
        {
            len[y][x-1]=len[y][x]+1;
            qu.push(make_pair(y,x-1));
        }
        if (x<m-1 && maze[y][x+1]!='#' && len[y][x+1]==-1)
        {
            len[y][x+1]=len[y][x]+1;
            qu.push(make_pair(y,x+1));
        }
    }
    cout<<-1<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```